# Remove a particular sub-string from string

Tags: php, file, string

I have following text after reading a file:

```
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Process Start
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Creating File
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Opening File
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Writing Text
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Closing File
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Sending File in email
06/16/2011 04:01:05 AM : Process End
```

I want to remove date and time in the beginning of each line like this:

```
Process Start
Creating File
Opening File
Writing Text
Closing File
Sending File in email
Process End
```

How can we do this with string matching technique ?

Thanks

Comment: Split each line of string (using AM or PM as condition) into 2 parts and pick the second part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be the following: (assuming the prefix is always the same length)

```
$output = '';
$tmp    = explode("\n",$input);

foreach($tmp as $t)
    $output .= substr($t,25)."\n";

echo $output;
```

First you `explode` the input into a variable by splitting it on every new line, and then for each line you remove the first 25 characters to create a new output.

http://codepad.org/ewuecNuU

Answer (score 2):

Date and time have constant length in your file. Use substr function to cut off 25 symbols from start of each line.

Comment: How to get each line separately and process it ??

Comment: @Student, if you look at my explanation I've provided code to do what IvanGL describes here.

Comment: use explode function: $lines = explode("\n", $text);

Answer (score 2):

If all strings are prefixed with text of the same length, use substring. If not, use regular expression matching.

Answer (score 2):

According to your example it seems that the best thing is to use `substr()` because the size of the prefix is always the same. But if you really need a matching technique it will look something like this:

```
$new_line = preg_replace('^/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\/ (?:AM|PM) : /', '', $line);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*): /', '', $input);
```

Comment: It is good but it is not working correctly when there is another `:` in message after first `:`

Comment: yes, but your question does not provide that information. Use karolis more verbose answere then.

Comment: Yes. Therefore I up-voted you.. But my actual file contains extra `:`. Anyway Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "text : to : remove :  text to keep";
$pos = strrpos($str, ":");
$str2 = substr($str, $pos+1);
echo $str2;
```

edit: changed strpos to strrpos, to find the last occurrence, as per comment below

Comment: This wouldn't work, there's `:` in the date as well, plus this would remove the ability to have `:` in the "text to keep".